# heightAnchor.constraint not change height of view

Tags: swift, constraints, ios-autolayout, autoresize, nslayoutanchor

I use this code:

```
func show(){
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height - 300).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

func hide(){
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height + 300).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

`show` function works fine, but `hide` function does not work and `heightAnchor` does not work.

Comment: do you delete all constraint before using `hide` function?

Comment: I use this code for delete : `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: no that code doesn't delete your previous setup constraint.it just turn off autolayout engine

Comment: use this `view.removeConstraints(constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint][NSLayoutConstraint])` to delete all constraint that you want

Comment: This will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042162/constraints-not-updating-when-keyboard-appears/52043090#52043090

Comment: @andesta.erfan i get this error `Cannot convert value of type '(NSLayoutConstraint).Type' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutConstraint'`

Comment: I use this : `view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)`. and this code remove all children constraints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First declare constraints

```
var heightArchonWhenShow = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height - 300)
var heightArchonWhenHide = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height + 300)
```

After init your constraints on ViewDidLoad

```
func setConstraints(){
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    heightArchonWhenShow.isActive = true
}
```

And simple active them , don't overwrite. Like this:

```
func show(){
    heightArchonWhenShow.isActive = true
    heightArchonWhenHide.isActive = false
}

func hide(){
    heightArchonWhenShow.isActive = false
    heightArchonWhenHide.isActive = true
}
```

If u want u can also animate changes, like that :

```
func hide(){
    heightArchonWhenShow.isActive = false
    heightArchonWhenHide.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer , Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to setup your constraint in a different function like maybe `setup()` and store them in some variable that you can modify after, I'll show you an example

```
var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setup() {
    constraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height)
}

func show() {
    if constraint != nil {
        constraint!.constant = constraint!.constant + 300
    }
}

func hide() {
    if constraint != nil {
        constraint!.constant = constraint!.constant - 300
    }
}
```

Comment: This wont even compile >:(

Comment: I made some edits, i did some mistakes before sorry :)
But i saw the other answer, it's better and more detailed :D

Answer (score 2):

You need only 1 var

```
var heightCon = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height - 300)
heightCon.isActive = true
```

Then manage it's constant value

```
func showOrHide(_ te:Bool){

   heightCon.constant = te ? view.frame.height - 300 : view.frame.height + 300

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```