# How can I resize the button? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, autolayout, size

How do I change the width and length of the button while the phone screen is in portrait or landscape mode?

I want this to be the button size when the screen is Portrait :

```
        View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
```

and when the screen is landscape :

```
        View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

and this is my code :

```
class CHATViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var View_Mor: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    View_Mor.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    View_Mor.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    View_Mor.centerYAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
    View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
 }


override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53740125/8374890

Comment: this isnt my awnser please help me @iOSArchitect.com

Comment: are your constraints working fine in portrait mode?

Comment: yes my friend @iOSArchitect.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use size classes to vary the width and length of the button.
Override traitCollectionDidChange method, this will be called when the iPhone has changed in different orientations. Using the horizontalSizeClass & verticalSizeClass from the traitCollection activate the required constraints.

```
import UIKit

class CHATViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var View_Mor: UIView!
    lazy var heightArchonWhenPortrait = View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140)
    lazy var widthArchonWhenPortrait = View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140)
    lazy var heightArchonWhenlandscap = View_Mor.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
    lazy var widthArchonWhenlandscap = View_Mor.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        View_Mor.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        View_Mor.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        View_Mor.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        heightArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = false
        widthArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = false
        heightArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = true
        widthArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = true
    }


    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        redoLayout(trait: traitCollection)
    }


    func redoLayout(trait:UITraitCollection) {
        if trait.horizontalSizeClass == .compact && trait.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
            heightArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = false
            widthArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = false
            heightArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = true
            widthArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = true
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            heightArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = false
            widthArchonWhenlandscap.isActive = false
            heightArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = true
            widthArchonWhenPortrait.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```